# Fedora 21 fedup CLI error

Tags: linux, backup, fedora, iso-image, yum

I'm trying to upgrade my Fedora 20 Atom netbook to F21 using the official CLI tools, as well as the KFUpgrade fedup GUI tool I found on SourceForge.  The ISO from getfedora.org wasn't recognized as a DVD image and regardless of invoking the CLI or GUI I keep getting this error:
fedup: error: argument --network: version must be higher than 21

Rawhide won't work either.  Pardon my potential noobishness, but I'm lost.  Might anyone know of a good YUM-based migration method?  Could the problem be my cheap i386 hardware?

Thanks for clicking...

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar problem trying to upgrade from Fedora 18 to Fedora 20. I'd had a previously failed attempt at doing the upgrade due to an SELinux problem, and it seems that my system was left in a half-modified state. In particular, various files under `/etc/` such as `/etc/fedora-release` had been updated so they reported the installed OS as the version which failed to install.

This file is used by Python's builtin `platform` module, which in turn is used by [`Fedup`](https://github.com/wgwoods/fedup/blob/33e2f0b84211f6174f2a38377d9684aa1ff4f0ca/fedup/commandline.py#L232). `Fedup` sees that the OS reports itself as being equal to or less that the version specified and refuses to execute.

My heavy handed solution was simply to modify all the files under `/etc/` back to the "correct" version. `cat /etc/fedora-release` will tell you what version the OS "thinks" it is, then do a `grep -ir '<that version name>'` (e.g. heisenberg for Fedora 20) and modify the files that are listed. Simply changing the version number was sufficient for me.

Once this is done, re-run all the usual `Fedup` stuff.

Comment: *Once this is done,* fix the SELinux permission policies and then *re-run all the usual Fedup stuff.*, otherwise it could fail again ;). I'd recommend you completely disable it during the update, and re-enable it after (and let it relabel the filesystem again).

Answer (score 0):

If you still are having issues try a newer iso or   try either of the following:

1)  fedup --network --ver 21  --productimg (optionally  add 'setenforce=1')

2) launch the installer with 'setenforce=1'   ## in both cases DON'T use the ' marks they are  merely  for  comand isolation purposes...